# Dynamically Created List of Arguments Passed to Variadic Function

Tags: c++, c++11

I was testing variadic functions hoping that I could use it to solve a problem in which I need to create an object holding arbitrary number of arguments. It actually works fine but the arguments passed to the function *createObject* would need to be dynamic. In the example below, only two arguments are passed to the constructor, but in the final program the number and the order in which arguments are passed should be arbitrary (the arguments always have the type Param though).

I can't seem to find a way of doing this. Any help, ideas etc. would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I found a couple of similar questions on Stackoverflow, but they are old and do no provide any accepted answer.

```
struct Vec3f { float x, y, z; };
struct Vec2f { float x, y; };

template<class T>
struct Param
{
    static const std::size_t size = sizeof(T);
    Param(const std::string &n) : name(n) {}
    std::string name;
};

typedef Param<Vec3f> ParamFloat3;
typedef Param<Vec2f> ParamFloat2;

void parseParameters(std::size_t &stride) {}

template<class T, typename ... Types>
void parseParameters(std::size_t &stride, const Param<T> &first, Types ... args)
{
    stride += first.size;
    parseParameters(stride, args ...);
}

template<class T, typename ... Types>
void createObject(const Param<T> &first, Types ... args)
{
    std::size_t stride = 0;
    parseParameters(stride, first, args...);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ParamFloat3 test1("T1");
    ParamFloat2 test2("T2");
    createObject(test1, test2); // would like to make this dynamic
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the arguments passed to the function `createObject` would need to be dynamic"? What does "dynamic" mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All kinds of template programming (including variadic templates) are resolved at compile-time. You'll need to pass a container (e.g an `std::vector`) to your functions.

**Edit :** If you need to pass parameters of different types (`Param<Vec3f>` and `Param<Vec2f>` are actually strictly different, despite coming from the same template), you will need to rely on polymorphism. Give all parameters the same base class, and use virtual functions or `dynamic_cast` to recover the correct behaviour.

The safest way to achieve that (and avoid *object slicing*) will be to use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Param>>` where Param is your base class.

Comment: So considering that ParamFloat2 and ParamFloat3 have a different type, I need to do something like this vector<Param> in which ParamFloat2 and 3 would actually be inherited from the parent class Param? The good old way? That's okay, just wanted to see if there was a new way of doing this with the new functions from C++11.

Comment: @user18490 C++ doesn't have heterogeneous container facilities, so : yes. Keep in mind that C++ types as first-class entities completely disappear after compilation. At runtime you're left with virtual functions (polymorphism), or `dynamic_cast` at best.

Comment: Sure, I understand thank you. I will wait a little while to see if anyone has anything to suggest and will accept your answer later on.

Comment: Edited and expanded my comment into my answer.

Comment: @user18490 C++11 has [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) which seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: @0x499602D2 again, std::tuple is compile-time only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the first argument as `Param<T>`, you can deduce the entire argument:

```c++
template<class Head, class... Tail>
void parseParameters(std::size_t& stride, Head&& head, Tail&&... tail)
{
    stride += head.size;
    parseParameters(stride, std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
}

template<class... Args>
void createObject(Args&&... args)
{
    std::size_t stride = 0;
    parseParameters(stride, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

You can also disable different overloads and enable others if you intend to have different functionality depending on the type.